# Returning a string value that is always alphanumeric

Tags: java, string, integer, while-loop

I am trying to create a string of six alphanumeric characters. The code below works fine most of the time but on the rare occasion a string of six alpha characters gets through, how can I ensure that the returned string is always alphanumeric?

```
String code = "";

while(!code.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
{
    code = Integer.toString((int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE), 36);
}

return code;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated attempts is possibly the simplest, but you have to check it contains a letter and a digit.

```
String code;
do {
    code = Integer.toString((int) (Math.random() * Integer.MAX_VALUE), 36);
    if (code.length() > 6)
       code = code.substring(0, 6);
} while(!code.matches(".*\\w.*") || !code.matches(".*\\d.*") || code.length() < 6);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `.+`? I think it should be `.*`

Comment: @BorisStrandjev You are right, it didnt take into account the length either.

Comment: All the strings have been alphanumeric so far, thanks a lot! What is the difference with the 'code'.+'code' and the 'code'.*'code'?

Comment: The difference between `.*` and `.+` is that the first requires a letter and a digit which is not the first or last character, the second allows it to any character.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this regex should ensure that the string is always alphanumeric (contains at least one letter and one number)

```
(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).+$
```

Comment: Using that regex expression I still get some strings that are just alpha characters. One such string was "irtyfi".